# Whenever I compile my program I'm unable to run the file gcc has created for me

Tags: c, file, gcc

Using my code below gcc creates an un-executable file. Also when I include my sort.h header file I get an error. Thanks to anyone willing to proof read my code.

The intended function of the program is to open the provided file and then sort it.

file_sorter.c:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
//#include <sort.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(int argc, char **argv){
    if(argc != 2) {
        printf("usage: file_sorter <filename>\n");
        exit (EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    char *out = "sorted.txt"; //declares the name of output file

    FILE *fp, *fileOUT; //Pointer to sort output data

    fp = fopen(*argv, "r");

    if(fp = NULL){ //checks that the file opened
        exit (EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    char *line = NULL; //Grabs the total amount of lines from the file
    size_t len = 0;
    int totalLines = getline(&line, &len, fp);

    char **array = (char**)malloc(totalLines * sizeof(char*));
    char singleline[totalLines]; //initial memory allocation for the file

    int i = 0;
    while(fgets(singleline, totalLines, fp) != NULL){
        array[i] = (char*) malloc (totalLines * sizeof(char));
        singleline[totalLines] = '\0';
        strcpy(array[i], singleline);
        i++;
    }//loading the file, and allocating memory as we go

    printf("unsorted file:\n");//prints the unsorted array
    for(i=0; i<totalLines; i++){
        printf("%s\n", array[i]);
    }

    fileOUT = fopen(out, "w");//opens the out file
    if(!fileOUT){
        exit (EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    printf("sorted file:\n");//prints out the sorted file
    for(i=0; i<totalLines; i++){
        fprintf(fileOUT, "%s", array[i]);
    }

    fclose(fp);//close the files
    fclose(fileOUT);

    for(i=0; i<totalLines; i++){//anti memory leak
        free(array[i]);
    }
    free(array);

    return 0;
}
```

sort.c:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stddef.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void quick(int *a, int n){
    if(n < 2){
        return;
    }
    int p = a[n /2];
    int *l = a;
    int *r = a + n -1;
    while( l <= r ){
        if( *l < p ){
            l++;
        }
        else if ( *r > p ){
            r--;
        }
        else {
            int t = *l;
            *l = *r;
            *r = t;
            l++;
            r--;
        }
    }
    quick( a, r - a + 1 );
    quick( l, a + n - l );
}

void insertion(int *a, const size_t n) {
    size_t i, j;
    int value;
    for (i = 1; i < n; i++) {
        value = a[i];
        for (j = i; j > 0 && value < a[j - 1]; j--) {
            a[j] = a[j - 1];
        }
        a[j] = value;
    }
}
```

sort.h:

```
#ifndef SORT_H
#define SORT_H
#include <stddef.h>

void quick(int *a, int n);
void insertion(int *a, const size_t n);
void readFile(char *a, char *b)

#endif /*SORT_H*/
```

makefile:

```
all: file_sorter.o sort.o
    gcc -Wall -o file_sorter file_sorter.o sort.o

file_sorter.o: file_sorter.c sort.h
    gcc -c file_sorter.c

sort.o: sort.c sort.h
    gcc -c sort.c

clean:
    rm -rf sort *.o
```

Comment: And what is the error? How do you run the executable?

Comment: Type this as the command prompt:

    `./file_sorter`

Unless it says something about "No such file or directory", then your program is running.

Comment: You misses a semicolon in your sort.h file after readFile(char *a, char *b)

Comment: I don't see an implementation of void readFile(char *a, char *b) in your sort.c, neither did you call it. Remove it then.

Comment: makefile looks fine. but this line `gcc creates an un-executable file.` confuse me. means what? any error? what you got and what you expect? can you focus it more?

Answer (score 1):

You are not opening anything (except attempting to open the calling program name):

```
fp = fopen(*argv, "r");
```

Recall `*argv` which is `argv[0]` is the calling program name (i.e. 'file_sorter'). You should use `argv[1]` for the first command line argument. I.e.:

```
fp = fopen(argv[1], "r");
```

to open the filename provided on the command line. Fix that then we will work on other issues.

Answer (score 1):

One error immediately stands out:

```
if(fp = NULL){ //checks that the file opened
```

That should be `==` (or just say `if (!fp)`). As it is, you're setting
`fp` to `NULL`. Since the expression evaluates to zero, it will not
exit. Instead, the remainder of the program will try to run using a null
file pointer.

Are all lines the same length? You appears to be reading the first line
to find out the line length here:

```
int totalLines = getline(&line, &len, fp);
```

If the first line contains the line count, then you're converting it
wrong. As it is, `totalLines` ends up with the length of the first line.

You also have a memory leak, because passing `NULL` tells `getline()` to
allocate a buffer, and you didn't free it.

If the first line is just a data line, you need to `rewind()` to read it
again for the data.

Always check the return value of `malloc()` to ensure it worked.

(Not an exhaustive list.)

Comment: By the way, using the `-Wall` option to `gcc` will help catch things like the first error. There are lots of warnings you can enable, check the man page.